# Delta function with variable argument

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I've got a double integral involving a delta function, but the complication is that the argument of the delta function depends on both variables that are being integrated over. It's something like this
\begin{equation}G=\iint \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}z\, f(x)\delta(g(z)x)\end{equation}
In the case I'm dealing with, $g(z)=\sqrt{a+z}$. If I wanted to do the $z$ integration first, would that be the same as integrating over all $z$ that satisfy $(a+z)x=0$ instead of $\sqrt{a+z}\,x=0$ as in a usual delta function integration?

Answer (score 3):

$$\forall a\ne0,\ \int f(x)\delta(ax)\mathrm dx=\frac1{|a|}f(0)\implies G=f(0)\int\frac{\mathrm dz}{|g(z)|}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just split up the delta function:

$$G = \iint dx dz f(x) \delta (g(z)x) = \int x f(x) \delta(x) dx \int \delta (g(z)) dz.$$